# simple rewrite in apache not showing up correctly

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to rewrite in apache. i want requests to somedir/try.html be rewritten to try.html, without the directory.
the problem is that all links on try.html point to the position relative to the physical location of the file. when try.html is served under somedir/try.html all links point to somedir/link.
i hope i explained my problem clear enough...

this is the code i used:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^try1.html$ http://www.domain.com/try.php
```

Comment: Well, and what is the question? If you want to make your scripts work on different URL, you need to use `reverse proxy` - but it's really just my guess